# Does **Top** have the $(Epi,ExtrMono-Source)$-factorization property?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Let us consider the category ${\bf Top}$ of topological spaces and continuous functions. Is it true that a mono-source $(f_i:A \to A_i)_{i \in I}$ is extremal if and only if $A$ is equipped with the weak topology induced by the $f_i$?

How can I prove using the above result that ${\bf Top}$ is a $(Epi,ExtrMono-Source)$-category?

My idea was to consider the following factorization of any $f_i$:

$$
A \to B \to A_i
$$
where $B$ is the subspace of the cartesian product $\prod A_i$ endowed with the subset topology and chosen so that $e: A \to B$ is surjective (I can always do it set-theoretically!). Now, I firstly ask whether $e$ is a morphism in **Top**

Furthermore, in the previous diagram, we have $\pi_i \circ m: B \to A_i$ where $\pi_i$ are the usual projections and $m$ is the inclusion from $B$ to $\prod A_i$. Is the source $(m_i)_I$ a mono-source (in **Top** a characterization is given by requiring that $x \neq y \implies \exists i \in I: \, f_i(x) \neq f_i(y)$)? Does the source $(m_i)_I$ satisfy the condition of extremality given in part $(1)$?

An indirect way to show part $(2)$ consists of using the result (see Chapter 22 of The Joy of Cats) according to ${\bf Top}$ is a topological construct (so that it is a $(Epi,ExtrMono-Source)$-category). But I need a direct proof.